# SQL Sum divided weight over adjoining months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have the following table (Sample):

```
+----+--------+-------+------+------------+
| ID | WEIGHT | MONTH | YEAR | CATEGORYID |
+----+--------+-------+------+------------+
|  1 | 0.5    |     1 | 2014 | A          |
|  1 | 0.5    |     1 | 2014 | A          |
|  1 | 0.5    |     2 | 2014 | A          |
|  1 | 0.2    |     2 | 2014 | C          |
|  1 | 0.2    |     2 | 2014 | C          |
|  2 | 1.0    |     2 | 2014 | B          |
|  2 | 1.0    |     2 | 2014 | B          |
+----+--------+-------+------+------------+
```

The Output I want would be like this (Sample):

```
+----+--------+-------+------+------------+
| ID | WEIGHT | MONTH | YEAR | CATEGORYID |
+----+--------+-------+------+------------+
|  1 | 1.5    |     1 | 2014 | A          |
|  1 | 1.5    |     2 | 2014 | A          |
|  1 | 0.4    |     1 | 2014 | C          |
|  1 | 0.4    |     2 | 2014 | C          |
|  2 | 2.0    |     2 | 2014 | B          |
|  2 | 2.0    |     3 | 2014 | B          |
+----+--------+-------+------+------------+
```

So, when the month breaks I still want to sum the weight from previous month into the current etc. I want to sum the weight on the specific ID & CategoryID.

Comment: Which database u r using? Oracle, Sql server, mysql?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works.

```
 select DISTINCT  ID,sum(WEIGHT) over (partition by categoryid order by categoryid) as WEIGHT,     
 MONTH,YEAR, CATEGORYID 
 from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID,
       Sum(s_weight)OVER(partition BY CATEGORYID, id),
       MONTH,
       YEAR,
       CATEGORYID
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               Sum(weight) AS s_weight,
               MONTH,
               YEAR,
               CATEGORYID
        FROM   Yourtable
        GROUP  BY ID,
                  MONTH,
                  YEAR,
                  CATEGORYID) a
```